# Can We Use the Old Chat Theme?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, design, chat

You may have noticed that the new site theme has been published.  Now, before the update, we had (in my opinion) one of the best looking, cleanest, easiest to read chatroom themes of any site on the network.  Now it's all blue, which you'd think would be fine, but I find it much less visual appealing, and harder to read.

Can we get the old *black n' green* theme back in the chatroom at least?  It's familiar, and some of us love it.  Or maybe an option to pick which one you want?  That could apply to the site theme as well.

Comment: [[meta-tag:status-bydesign]] - *"The only way to make sense out of change is to plunge into it, move with it and join the dance."*  — Alan Watts

Answer (score 3):

This is just a quick hack, but if you have grease monkey installed [this](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/57682539/oldbridge.user.js) script will revert the links and bottom chat bar to their old color.

Personally, I like the new theme, but I do agree that I found the black colour of the old bottom bar to be easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 0):

We did have a great theme but I do not think this one a bad one.

The clean blue/gray is a good combination for low contrast but good visibility. And I have to say that the links stand out in a very nice manner with their blue coloring as opposed to before, while you could see them, they were not as stand outish.

Overall, I like the new theme. I am not sure if letting user selection of a theme is even possible though but I would not be against that.

Comment: `low contrast but good visibility` confuses me.  So it can be *seen* very well (what), but Shog help you if you try to actually read or distinguish things?

Comment: @MatthewRead its not black on yellow high contrast and yet it is still readable (visible). Hope that clears that up.